# Updating a File's Content Google Drive API

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api

I've been working with Google Drive REST API v3 and I'm having difficulty trying to update a file. I can currently get the actual file from drive and read its contents (it is just a .txt file), but when I try to update the contents it does not work. I don't get any errors, but the file itself is never changed in Drive.

Here is the relevant code:

```
def rotate_and_update(the_file, service):
    """Rotates the names of the given file and updates its content.

    Checks to ensure that the given file has the same id as the text
    file in the drive.
    """

    file_id = the_file['id']
    file_metadata = the_file['name']

    if not file_id == '0BzLN2RWpS2IJU0pTeEdMbVJtNnc':
        raise RuntimeError("ID does not match file ID.")

    try:
        # gets file content and rotates the strings
        content = service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id).execute()

        file = service.files().get(fileId=file_id).execute()

        names = content.split()
        new_content = "\n".join(names[1:] + names[:1])

        print(content + "\n\n" + new_content)

        # updates the file with the new content
        media_body = MediaFileUpload(
            new_content, mimetype="text/plain", resumable=True)

        updated_file = service.files().update(
            fileId=file_id,
            body=file,
            media_body=media_body).execute()

        return updated_file

    except IOError:
        return None

def main():
   """Uses Google Drive API to obtain a file with a list of names, rotates
   the names, and updates the file with the new content.

   Obtains credentials through google
   """
   credentials = get_credentials()
   http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
   service = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=http)

   results = service.files().list(
       pageSize=10,fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
   items = results.get('files', [])
   print(items[0])

   rotate_and_update(items[0], service)
```

I have the correct credentials as well. Please let me know of anything I am doing wrong, thanks!

Edit: Error Code as follows

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "on_call_tracker.py", line 109, in <module>
    main()
  File "on_call_tracker.py", line 106, in main
    rotate_and_update(items[0], service)
  File "on_call_tracker.py", line 78, in rotate_and_update
    new_content, mimetype="text/plain", resumable=True)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\oauth2client\_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\http.py", line 545, in __init__
    fd = open(self._filename, 'rb')
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: 'Mac\nDennis\nDee\nFrank\nWaitress\nArtemis\nCricket\nCountry\nMac\nCharlie'`enter code here`
```

Comment: Can you add a link to the docs you were referring to?

Comment: Sure thing [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/update) is the api docs and I was looking at an example from the v2 docs [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update#examples)

Comment: I realise it's not a direct answer to your question, but you might want to look into the [`pydrive`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyDrive) module for a slightly more friendly way of interacting with Google Drive

Comment: Heh yeah, I've been looking into it and it would 100% be easier, I was just trying to familiarize myself with google's api before I try a 3rd party

Comment: Can you log the errors in `except`? Possibly log it as an HTTP error like in the [V2 docs](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update#examples) link.

Comment: Just edited it in, it seems like MediaFileUpload takes in the file path as its body, and I was putting in the new text content. Is there no way to change the content of a text file in drive without uploading a new file?

Comment: @AJwr Its not "uploading a new file" in this case. Its just *updating* the existing file's content to a newer version.

Comment: Besides, in python, all it takes to put a bunch of text in a file is this: `open('new_content.txt','w').write(new_content)`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible. You need to read https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/media_upload#extending-mediaupload to see how to create a subclass that takes dynamic content rather than a file name.